# Struggling to parse different text files based on their delimiters

Tags: java, split, delimiter

Ive been working on this on and off today.

Here is my method, which basically needs to accept a .data (txt) file location, and then go through the contents of that text file and break it up into strings based on the delimiters present. These are the 2 files.
The person file.

```
Person ID,First Name,Last Name,Street,City
1,Ola,Hansen,Timoteivn,Sandnes

2,Tove,Svendson,Borgvn,Stavanger
3,Kari,Pettersen,Storgt,Stavanger
```

The order file.

```
Order ID|Order Number|Person ID
10|2000|1
11|2001|2
12|2002|1
13|2003|10


public static void openFile(String url) {
        //initialize array for data to be held
        String[][] myStringArray = new String[10][10];
        int row = 0;
        try {
            //open the file
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(url);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            String strLine;
            //Read File Line By Line
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                //ignores any blank entries 
                if (!"".equals(strLine)) {
                    //splits by comma(\\| for order) and places individually into array 
                    String[] splitStr = new String[5];
                    //splitStr = strLine.split("\\|");
                    /*
                     * This is the part that i am struggling with getting to work.
                     */

                    if (strLine.contains("\\|")) {
                        splitStr = strLine.split("\\|");
                    } else if (strLine.contains(",")) {
                        splitStr = strLine.split(",");
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("error no delimiter detected");
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
                        myStringArray[row][i] = splitStr[i];
                        System.out.println(myStringArray[row][i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            //Close the input stream
            br.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

The person file is correctly read and parsed. But the order file with the "|" delimiter is having none of it. I just get 'null' printouts.

Whats confusing me is that when i just have splitStr = strLine.split("\|"); It works but i need this method to be able to detect the delimiter present and then apply the correct split.

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Use a CSV parsing library and specify which delimiter you need. Fewer lines of code, fewer errors, more time for a drink with friends, more happiness... For example: opencsv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the fact that this should be done using a CSV library, the reason this code is failing is that [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) doesnt accept a regular expression. Remove the escape characters so the pipe character can be detected

```
if (strLine.contains("|")) {
```

Comment: Well i feel silly. That's worked thank you. I just assumed it would be similar to the split method. That is beyond annoying thank you very much for your help!!